# How to get data with condition SQL QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql

So first of all, I have 2 table. The first one is the categories

```
Id     Name     
------------
1   Interior      
2   Eksterior    
3   Display
```

then the secon table is history which the data is the task I've finished

```
Id     category_name    category_id    date (month)     User Id 
---------------------------------------------------------------
001    Interior            1               3             1084
002    Eksterior           2               3             1084
003    Interior            1               4             1089
004    Eksterior           2               4             1085
005    Display             3               4             1085
```

and what I want is to get categories by month, user id and know which one already done and not done from history, like this

example the data in March with user id 1084 :

```
Id     Name     Status     
---------------------------
1   Interior     done      
2   Eksterior    done      
3   Display    not done
```

or like this :

```
Id     Name     Status    
--------------------------
1   Interior     1       
2   Eksterior    1       
3   Display      0
```

if the category in history table exist, the status will be 1 for done and 0 for not done.

this is my query before :

```
SELECT c.id, c.category, c.id=h.category_id status FROM categories c, history h WHERE MONTH(h.created_at)
```

I keep retrieving the wrong result for my query. Please help me..

Comment: How do we know done/not done status? Or, why doesn't month 4 count for Display?

Comment: Why do you repeat the category name in the second table? The category ID should be enough, you can get its name from the categories table.

Comment: Where does the row with Name = Display and Date = 3 come from?

Comment: because i want to get the data per month... my parameter is month=3

Comment: its from created date @Barmar

Comment: Where is that in the input tables you show?

Comment: @barmar looks like date is the month number from the first query, and the results are saying "month 3 is not done for display". I don't think month 4 is represented in the desired result set

Comment: Show us your query.

Comment: You probably need a LEFT JOIN between the categories and history tables.

Comment: SELECT c.id, c.category, c.id=h.category_id status FROM categories c, history h WHERE MONTH(h.created_at) .. this is my query

Comment: thank you so much guys and sorry for the unclear question.. it solved with left join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  categories c
  LEFT JOIN history h on h.category_id = c.id AND h."date (month)" = 3
```

..will get you towards what you want: there will be NULL in the row from history table, for category Display; you can use this "is or is not null" to create your `done/not done` column

Comment: thank you !! I dont know about left and right join and know you save me.. thank you so much and sorry for the unclear question

Comment: Here's the elevator-pitch intro to left join: `a LEFT JOIN b` keeps all rows from a, and adds in only those from b that match, or puts NULL for those that don't match. You should avoid mentioning `b` in the WHERE clause, because nothing is ever equal to null so the NULL rows will be lost (behaves like INNER join). This is why I put the `date(month)` in the ON clause instead, so that `Display` category row doesnt get lost